# Viewport units scale with changes in both width and height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, viewport-units

I was creating a venn-style diagram for a project and came up with this approach:

https://codepen.io/webconsult/pen/KQMMJm

```
<div class="venn-diagram">
  <div class="circle-business"><span class="label">Business</span></div>
  <div class="circle-design"><span class="label">Design</span></div>
  <div class="circle-technology"><span class="label">Technology</span</div>
</div>
```

---

```
// Variables
$circle-width: 35vmin;
$horizontal-displacement: 0.40;
$vertical-displacement: 0.70;
$standard-margin: 20px;

// Color palette
$green: #00d6a4;
$pink: #f46197;
$dark-blue: #0a2342;
$medium-blue: #274060;
$light-blue: #01baef;

// Pallette assignments
$main: $medium-blue;
$main-dark: $dark-blue;
$main-light: $light-blue;
$identity: $green;
$emphasis: $pink;

// Mixins
@mixin center-children {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@mixin center-children-top {
  @include center-children;
  > * {
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}

@mixin circle($diameter) {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: $diameter;
  height: $diameter;
}

// Instance styling starts here

.venn-diagram {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 1.7 * $circle-width;
    @include center-children-top;
    margin: (2*$standard-margin) $standard-margin;
}

.circle-technology, .circle-design, .circle-business {
    @include circle($circle-width);
    @include center-children;
    .label {
        font-size: $circle-width/8;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
}

.circle-design {
    position: relative;
    background-color: $emphasis;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circle-business {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -($circle-width * $horizontal-displacement);
    margin-top: ($circle-width * $vertical-displacement);
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: fade-out($main-light, 0.1);
}

.circle-technology {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: ($circle-width * $horizontal-displacement);
    margin-top: ($circle-width * $vertical-displacement);
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: fade-out($main, 0.1);
}

p.introduction {
    padding: 0 $standard-margin * 2;
}
```

It works fairly well and most importantly it scales perfectly when you resize your browser because I chose to us `vw` units for the sizes of the circles, their individual displacement in relation to each other and for font sizes.

So I thought all was good, but now I realize that it does not actuall adapt very well to different screen sizes and aspect ratios.

It was designed to work well on mobile in portrait mode, where the figure would take up most of the available horizontal space, but once you turn the phone into landscape mode it will maintain the same ratio between the width of the display and the width of the figure, so you can no longer see the top and bottom of the figure, but what's worse is that once you watch it on a desktop/laptop the size will be blown up to mad dimensions and it will just look plain weird.

So I need some sort of "art direction" - i.e. I need to be able to set different relationships between width of the figure and screen size.

I figured I could easily do that with media queries. I could just set different values for the `$circle-width` variable with media queries and have them affect different use scenarios. To my dissapointment I discovered that it's not quite so easy as the SASS variables are written at compile time. I've sort of lost focus a bit and cannot figure out how to scale this figure for different displays. Suggestions?

Comment: "To my dissapointment I discovered that it's not quite so easy as the SASS variables are written at compile time" -- why is that a problem? You need to define a media query for each device breakpoint you want, and use that to override different sizes in elements you need to. e.g. a media query for `max-width: 600px` and have a smaller (and maybe not `vw`) width

Comment: Here is my attempt at doing that. Does not work :( The reason I went with `vm` is that it's easier to maintain intrinsic ratios - i.e. the relationship between height and width of the circles is maintained. I think I've done this before using width in percent and setting the height with padding bottom, which I'm thinking about falling back to, but that should not have anything to do with media queries. https://codepen.io/webconsult/pen/rJLMXE

Comment: Should I assume my answer weren't useful?

Comment: Sorry. Just have not had the time to test it before now.

Comment: That is perfectly fine :) ... just wanted to check in.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a portrait/landscape issue, and for that you can use `orientation` with the query.

As mentioned, using `vmin` will choose the smaller of the viewport width/height, though often it is more to it than just that. With `orientation` you can both fine-tune `vw`/`vh` and control the positioning much better, than using a given width as break point.

Also, when setting up the query, you need to repeat the classes like this for it to work properly:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

  .venn-diagram {
      height: 1.7 * $circle-width-portrait;
  }

  .circle-technology, .circle-design, .circle-business {
      @include circle($circle-width-portrait);

      .label {
        font-size: $circle-width-portrait/8;
      }
  }
  .circle-business {
      margin-left: -($circle-width-portrait * $horizontal-displacement);
      margin-top: ($circle-width-portrait * $vertical-displacement);
  }
  .circle-technology {
      margin-left: ($circle-width-portrait * $horizontal-displacement);
      margin-top: ($circle-width-portrait * $vertical-displacement);
  }
}
```

---

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQXmKd)

Stack snippet

```css
.venn-diagram {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 85vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 40px 20px;
}
.venn-diagram > * {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.circle-technology, .circle-design, .circle-business {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.circle-technology .label, .circle-design .label, .circle-business .label {
  font-size: 6.25vh;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.circle-design {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f46197;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle-business {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20vh;
  margin-top: 35vh;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(1, 186, 239, 0.9);
}

.circle-technology {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20vh;
  margin-top: 35vh;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: rgba(39, 64, 96, 0.9);
}

p.introduction {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .venn-diagram {
    height: 85vw;
  }

  .circle-technology, .circle-design, .circle-business {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
  }
  .circle-technology .label, .circle-design .label, .circle-business .label {
    font-size: 6.25vw;
  }

  .circle-business {
    margin-left: -20vw;
    margin-top: 35vw;
  }

  .circle-technology {
    margin-left: 20vw;
    margin-top: 35vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="venn-diagram">
  <div class="circle-business"><span class="label">Business</span></div>
  <div class="circle-design"><span class="label">Design</span></div>
  <div class="circle-technology"><span class="label">Technology</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not exclusively a portrait/landscape problem. It looks plain bad if the figure gets blown up beyond a certain size. But you did solve the problem for me. The problem is that I do have to declare all of the rules again in a separate query. Seems very redundant, but maybe I'll look into setting up another mixin.